# Make a Single EXE from BATCH and 2 EXEs

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have a script (a.bat) that calls 2 executables (b.exe and c.exe) and I would like to create a single exe that would call a.bat automatically.

Is it possible?

Any simple program to do this?

Ps.: Info: The Exe's do make other files that are deleted in the end

Comment: How do you mean you want to call a.bat automatically? Isn't a.bat the file you execute anyways?

Comment: I think I over said it. I want to create a a.exe that includes all the necessary files inside it.

Comment: Ah right, in that case then I would go with atzz's answer, a self extracting archive or maybe even a software installer tool like Smart Install Maker would be your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, no.

The simplest way to accomplish this with off-the-shelf tools is to use an archiver that can create self-extracting archives and allows to specify a file to run after extraction. For example, free [Info-Zip](http://info-zip.org) tools support an [autorun command](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzipsfx.html#AUTORUN%20COMMAND). [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) (commercial) allows to define complex scripts with GUI.

An install engine can be used for the same purpose. For a couple of examples, there are  [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) and [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) (both free).

A (relatively) more complex solution is to write a third executable that will extract payload from its resources and run the batch file. This way you have full control over what happens.

Comment: +1 for Inno Setup. This is one of the scenarios where the program fits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This One:[Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/downloads/Bat_To_Exe_Converter.zip)

It has the "Include" option that can include the exe file
when the compiled exe file run
it will release it 
and you can run it!

Comment: Thanks for the link! BTW, that site contains some other utilities which look useful (but site design is very strange, you can see only one program at a time and have to click to scroll through the list... weird).